# large file stops downloading after some time in php

Tags: php

I've build a script to download a rar/zip file upto 2Gb, it start download but stops after some time. What will be the reason? I've changed setting in `php.ini` and restarted the server too but nothing works: http://filecubic.com/info2.php : Following is the code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
$filePath = "http://filecubic.com/download/1071/1.8_gb_fileteste_1452312029.rar"; // set your download file path here. 
download($filePath); // calls download function 

function download($filePath) {
if (!empty($filePath)) {
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($filePath);
    $fileName = $fileInfo['basename'];
    $fileExtnesion = $fileInfo['extension'];
    $default_contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    $content_types_list = mimeTypes();
    // to find and use specific content type, check out this IANA page : http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml 
    if (array_key_exists($fileExtnesion, $content_types_list)) {
        $contentType = $content_types_list[$fileExtnesion];
    } else {
        $contentType = $default_contentType;
    }
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $size = filesize($filePath);
        $offset = 0;
        $length = $size;
        //HEADERS FOR PARTIAL DOWNLOAD FACILITY BEGINS 
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
            preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
            $offset = intval($matches[1]);
            $length = intval($matches[2]) - $offset;
            $fhandle = fopen($filePath, 'r');
            fseek($fhandle, $offset); // seek to the requested offset, this is 0 if it's not a partial content request 
            $data = fread($fhandle, $length);
            fclose($fhandle);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length) . '/' . $size);
        }//HEADERS FOR PARTIAL DOWNLOAD FACILITY BEGINS 
        //USUAL HEADERS FOR DOWNLOAD 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=" . $fileName);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $contentType);
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
        $chunksize = 8 * (1024 * 1024); //8MB (highest possible fread length) 
        if ($size > $chunksize) {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'rb');
            $buffer = '';
            while (!feof($handle) && (connection_status() === CONNECTION_NORMAL)) {
                $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
                print $buffer;
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
            if (connection_status() !== CONNECTION_NORMAL) {
                echo "Connection aborted";
            }
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($filePath);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'File does not exist!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'There is no file to download!';
}
}

/* Function to get correct MIME type for download */

function mimeTypes() {
/* Just add any required MIME type if you are going to download something not listed here. */
$mime_types = array("323" => "text/h323",
    "acx" => "application/internet-property-stream",
    "ai" => "application/postscript",
    "aif" => "audio/x-aiff",
    "aifc" => "audio/x-aiff",
    "aiff" => "audio/x-aiff",
    "asf" => "video/x-ms-asf",
    "asr" => "video/x-ms-asf",
    "asx" => "video/x-ms-asf",
    "au" => "audio/basic",
    "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
    "axs" => "application/olescript",
    "bas" => "text/plain",
    "bcpio" => "application/x-bcpio",
    "bin" => "application/octet-stream",
    "bmp" => "image/bmp",
    "c" => "text/plain",
    "cat" => "application/vnd.ms-pkiseccat",
    "cdf" => "application/x-cdf",
    "cer" => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
    "class" => "application/octet-stream",
    "clp" => "application/x-msclip",
    "cmx" => "image/x-cmx",
    "cod" => "image/cis-cod",
    "cpio" => "application/x-cpio",
    "crd" => "application/x-mscardfile",
    "crl" => "application/pkix-crl",
    "crt" => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
    "csh" => "application/x-csh",
    "css" => "text/css",
    "dcr" => "application/x-director",
    "der" => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
    "dir" => "application/x-director",
    "dll" => "application/x-msdownload",
    "dms" => "application/octet-stream",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "dot" => "application/msword",
    "dvi" => "application/x-dvi",
    "dxr" => "application/x-director",
    "eps" => "application/postscript",
    "etx" => "text/x-setext",
    "evy" => "application/envoy",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "fif" => "application/fractals",
    "flr" => "x-world/x-vrml",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "gtar" => "application/x-gtar",
    "gz" => "application/x-gzip",
    "h" => "text/plain",
    "hdf" => "application/x-hdf",
    "hlp" => "application/winhlp",
    "hqx" => "application/mac-binhex40",
    "hta" => "application/hta",
    "htc" => "text/x-component",
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htt" => "text/webviewhtml",
    "ico" => "image/x-icon",
    "ief" => "image/ief",
    "iii" => "application/x-iphone",
    "ins" => "application/x-internet-signup",
    "isp" => "application/x-internet-signup",
    "jfif" => "image/pipeg",
    "jpe" => "image/jpeg",
    "jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
    "jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    "js" => "application/x-javascript",
    "latex" => "application/x-latex",
    "lha" => "application/octet-stream",
    "lsf" => "video/x-la-asf",
    "lsx" => "video/x-la-asf",
    "lzh" => "application/octet-stream",
    "m13" => "application/x-msmediaview",
    "m14" => "application/x-msmediaview",
    "m3u" => "audio/x-mpegurl",
    "man" => "application/x-troff-man",
    "mdb" => "application/x-msaccess",
    "me" => "application/x-troff-me",
    "mht" => "message/rfc822",
    "mhtml" => "message/rfc822",
    "mid" => "audio/mid",
    "mny" => "application/x-msmoney",
    "mov" => "video/quicktime",
    "movie" => "video/x-sgi-movie",
    "mp2" => "video/mpeg",
    "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
    "mpa" => "video/mpeg",
    "mpe" => "video/mpeg",
    "mpeg" => "video/mpeg",
    "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
    "mpp" => "application/vnd.ms-project",
    "mpv2" => "video/mpeg",
    "ms" => "application/x-troff-ms",
    "mvb" => "application/x-msmediaview",
    "nws" => "message/rfc822",
    "oda" => "application/oda",
    "p10" => "application/pkcs10",
    "p12" => "application/x-pkcs12",
    "p7b" => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
    "p7c" => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
    "p7m" => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
    "p7r" => "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
    "p7s" => "application/x-pkcs7-signature",
    "pbm" => "image/x-portable-bitmap",
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "pfx" => "application/x-pkcs12",
    "pgm" => "image/x-portable-graymap",
    "pko" => "application/ynd.ms-pkipko",
    "pma" => "application/x-perfmon",
    "pmc" => "application/x-perfmon",
    "pml" => "application/x-perfmon",
    "pmr" => "application/x-perfmon",
    "pmw" => "application/x-perfmon",
    "pnm" => "image/x-portable-anymap",
    "pot" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "ppm" => "image/x-portable-pixmap",
    "pps" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "prf" => "application/pics-rules",
    "ps" => "application/postscript",
    "pub" => "application/x-mspublisher",
    "qt" => "video/quicktime",
    "ra" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    "ram" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    "ras" => "image/x-cmu-raster",
    "rgb" => "image/x-rgb",
    "rmi" => "audio/mid",
    "roff" => "application/x-troff",
    "rtf" => "application/rtf",
    "rtx" => "text/richtext",
    "scd" => "application/x-msschedule",
    "sct" => "text/scriptlet",
    "setpay" => "application/set-payment-initiation",
    "setreg" => "application/set-registration-initiation",
    "sh" => "application/x-sh",
    "shar" => "application/x-shar",
    "sit" => "application/x-stuffit",
    "snd" => "audio/basic",
    "spc" => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
    "spl" => "application/futuresplash",
    "src" => "application/x-wais-source",
    "sst" => "application/vnd.ms-pkicertstore",
    "stl" => "application/vnd.ms-pkistl",
    "stm" => "text/html",
    "svg" => "image/svg+xml",
    "sv4cpio" => "application/x-sv4cpio",
    "sv4crc" => "application/x-sv4crc",
    "t" => "application/x-troff",
    "tar" => "application/x-tar",
    "tcl" => "application/x-tcl",
    "tex" => "application/x-tex",
    "texi" => "application/x-texinfo",
    "texinfo" => "application/x-texinfo",
    "tgz" => "application/x-compressed",
    "tif" => "image/tiff",
    "tiff" => "image/tiff",
    "tr" => "application/x-troff",
    "trm" => "application/x-msterminal",
    "tsv" => "text/tab-separated-values",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "uls" => "text/iuls",
    "ustar" => "application/x-ustar",
    "vcf" => "text/x-vcard",
    "vrml" => "x-world/x-vrml",
    "wav" => "audio/x-wav",
    "wcm" => "application/vnd.ms-works",
    "wdb" => "application/vnd.ms-works",
    "wks" => "application/vnd.ms-works",
    "wmf" => "application/x-msmetafile",
    "wps" => "application/vnd.ms-works",
    "wri" => "application/x-mswrite",
    "wrl" => "x-world/x-vrml",
    "wrz" => "x-world/x-vrml",
    "xaf" => "x-world/x-vrml",
    "xbm" => "image/x-xbitmap",
    "xla" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xlc" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xlm" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xlt" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xlw" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xof" => "x-world/x-vrml",
    "xpm" => "image/x-xpixmap",
    "xwd" => "image/x-xwindowdump",
    "z" => "application/x-compress",
    "rar" => "application/x-rar-compressed",
    "zip" => "application/zip");
return $mime_types;
}
```

Comment: try increasing max time limit with set_time_limit(0);

Comment: @MarinoDiClemente I've tried this too but unfortunately didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to download that file as a "chunks", something like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
while(!feof($file))
{
    print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

If you have Apache, you can use [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), that makes the download simpler and faster. You just output a header and the module takes care of the rest.

Here is great article about downloading files using PHP: [The “right way” to handle file downloads in PHP](http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/).